# while creating an android studio project it is not showing java and kotlin option and not showing full templates

Tags: android, android-studio

I am beginner in android developer and when I am creating a new project in android studio there are showing less templates.[this is the image which is normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33dw8.jpg)
[This is what is coming in mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B24A2.png)

Can anyone fix this.

I an expecting the image which is normal.